# Converting from one type to another

Tags: typescript, types

I have a type, `UncalculatedType`, that represents an object carrying a value.

My programme will take that value and calculate other properties based on it, which it will then attach to the object, creating a `CalculatedType`. The properties are calculated in series and will be attached one by one.

```js
interface UncalculatedType {
  value: string
}

interface CalculatedType {
  value: string
  calculatedProperty: number
  anotherCalculatedProperty: string[]
}
```

The problem comes when trying to convert from one type to another:

```js
let myThing: UncalculatedType = { value: "something" }

myThing.calculatedProperty = calc(myThing.value)
// Error: Property 'calculatedProperty' does not exist on type 'UncalculatedType'.

(myThing as CalculatedType).calculatedProperty = calc(myThing.value)
mything.anotherCalculatedProperty = calc2(myThing.calculatedProperty)
// Error: Property 'anotherCalculatedProperty' does not exist on type 'UncalculatedType'.
```

Even after popping a type assertion, `myThing` is still considered `UncalculatedType`.

What's the best way to go about this?

I could make another object to hold the new values:

```js
let myNewThing: CalculatedType = {
   ...myThing,
   calculatedProperty: calc(myThing.value)
}
```

...but then I'd only be able to add to it the first property, before Typescript complains that `CalculatedType` is missing `anotherCalculatedProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your use-case: e.g. do the calc functions only need the `UncalculatedType` or does `calcB` also need the result of `calcA`?

When `calcB` does not need the result of `calcA`, you can return [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) from the individual functions:

see [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=35&ssc=45&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKogXANggrluSAEwBUBPABxQG8AoZZAN21wgC5kBnMKUAc1oBfWrRi4MYYAHsQyTDgCCAHhLIIAD0gginNBmx4CxclQB8AChhSpHEgEpbyAGTI6DBvMOEIRAApQpKigwMg4QXABbACNoIVd6dygIMFwoWTd3TIA6HKspABoEzI8DfG8-AKCQjgBGACYi5GFhETEJaVlPACEVNU0IbV10TzLjSggLPNsHZFUXDIY4ECkwAAtoAGFSox9-QOhqrh5%20AG0AXTiF5CSUtPji9xysvMKHxeW1ze3yvarQ5BOAHI4ID8shAVFARdMs0RAgZNxkFM9CMdqRxsgALz3dzMLCsDiA7i8EB8AC0eNYgKEcIRYCR1gUWLkBgUlmsdgA3LR4SBOFIsBAslgpHx2VIFFlKRAuTyEQKhSKxXlJaifpUDmRZXK%20fS8l1md1xQpZbz%20YLhaLxV0pSwZdyzQrLcrrDa1cRfprTfKLUrrVklit1lAtjhRrsNcEtdygA)

```js
interface UncalculatedType {
  value: string
}

function calcA<T extends UncalculatedType>(foo: T): T & {
    calculatedProperty: number
} {
    return {
        ...foo,
        calculatedProperty: 12
    }
}


function calcB<T extends UncalculatedType>(foo: T): T & {
    anotherCalculatedProperty: string[]
} {
    return {
        ...foo,
        anotherCalculatedProperty: ['a', 'b']
    }
}

const foo: UncalculatedType = {
    value: 'string-value'
}

const fooA = calcA(foo);
console.log(fooA.value);
console.log(fooA.calculatedProperty);

const fooB = calcB(fooA);
console.log(fooB.value);
console.log(fooB.calculatedProperty);
console.log(fooB.anotherCalculatedProperty);
```

When `calcB` needs the result of `calcA`, you may use [Pick<>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk): see [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJwDYIK4bpAEwBUBPABxQG8AoZO5AN02wgC5kBnMKUAc1voJMOPIQAKUAPYUoYEuxDYAtgCNoAunBCSwAC2josufBAITp0Oey48QvANoBdagF9q1GNhAIwwSSGQhLABBAAoYSUl2MWAEAGsAHkMRE2JyCAAaZAByJgwWbIA+AEpo2MTk40JSCizc5ghs5AAfHKCU8SkZOSLkGnpkKAgwbCgA-oH6ADoZiMkMjUn2qtNzbvlkAEYAJkW3N3dPb19-QOEAIXDIsvik4RW02py8gpa2+9FVrssSItK0D6pGpURZDEZjPqLAYzKZzBaTehaHT6KCVT5mb6yDb2bJwbJ1FTZZwDfbuBD+LjIObBZAAXjOIVCEzoLzYORsfAAtKzsq5igBuajkkAcSQYCBTDCSXhXSTBKasgVCiliiVSmXUqbLdFrH5K5UisBUyLnOkMhCXalK4Wi8WS6Wy84KhrWlV29WOrWAzoWLGukWq+0ak1TJF6Azer6+uRKoA)

```
interface CalculatedType {
    value: string
    calculatedProperty: number
    anotherCalculatedProperty: string[]
}

function calcA(foo: Pick<CalculatedType, 'value'>): Pick<CalculatedType, 'value' | 'calculatedProperty'> {
    return {
        ...foo,
        calculatedProperty: 12
    }
}


function calcB(foo: Pick<CalculatedType, 'value' | 'calculatedProperty'>): CalculatedType {
    return {
        ...foo,
        anotherCalculatedProperty: ['a', 'b']
    }
}

const fooA = calcA({
    value: 'string-value'
});
console.log(fooA.value);
console.log(fooA.calculatedProperty);

const fooB = calcB(fooA);
console.log(fooB.value);
console.log(fooB.calculatedProperty);
console.log(fooB.anotherCalculatedProperty);
```

And finally a trivial solution (just for the sake of completeness) - [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJwDYIK4bpAEwBUBPABxQG8AoZO5AN02wgC5kBnMKUAc1voJMOPIQAKUAPYUoYEuxDYAtgCNoAunBCSwAC2josufBAITp0Oey48QvANoBdagF9q1GNhAIwwSSGQhLABBAAomDBZrbj4ASmQaemQoCDBsKACARgAmAG5Xd09vX39A4QAhcOY2Thi7ABoyo1FTcxkrZEVVaHjE%20hS0jOR7AHI4EcaRlRHHfLdqBH8uRmrkAF5kEZs%20AFoIlhH8xZBloJETMyl2knWmhDD9iFijpbBkLR19KENz8SvLG4bM6VR6NM7GP4WWQkZ7uY6nYQQ0ykCjsH5I4jkFAbPp0UEaO4YtoA%20oEj56AyIlqXKFyVxAA):

```
interface CalculatedType {
    value: string
    calculatedProperty: number
    anotherCalculatedProperty: string[]
}

function calcA(value: string) {
    return 12;
}

function calcB(value: string, calculatedProperty: number) {
    return ['a', 'b'];
}

const value = 'string-value';
const calculatedProperty = calcA(value);
const anotherCalculatedProperty = calcB(value, calculatedProperty);

const calculatedType: CalculatedType = {
    value,
    calculatedProperty,
    anotherCalculatedProperty
}
```

I personally prefer the last solution because every function is concise and only gets the input parameters that it needs, and outputs a single calculation value. This way, the functions are easy to test and easy to reuse (they are not tied to your interface definition).
But as already mentioned: it depends on the use-case.

Comment: The properties are calculated in series, one after the other, each depending on the value calculated before it. The example in my question is a simplification of lots of properties that need to be calculated: my object will start off as `UncalculatedType`, before slowly transitioning to `CalculatedType` which represents an object with a full set of properties. I'm not sure how well creating an intersection type for each combination of those properties will scale...?